# The generalized Pythagorean property of Bregman divergence

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

So suppose a function $f$ is strictly convex and continuously differentiable. The Bregman divergence associated with $f$ is
\begin{equation}
D_f(x,y) = f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^{T}(x-y), \forall x,y\in dom(f).
\end{equation}

I would like to prove that it satisfies the generalized Pythagorean property: let $X$ be a convex set and for any $y \in dom(f)$, its projection onto $X$ is the point $y^* = argmin_{x \in X} D_f(x,y)$, then $D_f(x,y) \geq D(x,y^*) + D(y^*,y)$ for any $x \in X$.

I have been trying this for hours but still can't prove it. The farthest I have is showing that
\begin{equation}
D(x,y^*) + D(y^*,y) = f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y^*)^{T}(x-y^*) - \nabla f(y)^{T}(y^*-y)
\end{equation},
and
\begin{equation}
D(x,y) = f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^{T}(x-y),
\end{equation}
I tried to subtract the first expression with the second, and the difference is
\begin{equation}
[\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(y^*)]^{T}(x-y^*),
\end{equation}
but I am not sure even I can show it's non-positive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let us define $g(x) := D_f(x,y)$. Then, $y^*$ minimizes $g$ over the set $X$. Thus...?

Comment: Thanks but I still can’t see the connection…? Perhaps I missed a fundamental point about convex functions?

Comment: You have to write down the first order optimality conditions.